# Stripe Payment Error - StripeCheckout.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I am having a problem implementing stripe on my production server.  I use MAMP on my computer and it works fine on there but when I put it on my live server it does not work.  Here is the info, let me know if I forgot any details!

I am using the standard overlay StripeCheckout.open method of checking out... none of my own payment info forms

```js
$("#pay_now").click(function() {                        
    var value = checking();
    var amount = $('#total_summary').html();
    amount = amount.replace('$','');
    amount = Math.round(parseFloat(amount) * 100);
                                    
    if (value == 0) {
        var token = function(res) {
            var $input = $('<input type=hidden name=stripeToken />').val(res.id);
            $('form').append($input).submit();
        };
                    
        StripeCheckout.open({
            key: '<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>',
            address:     false,
            amount:      amount,
            currency:    'cad',
            panelLabel:  'Pay',
            token:       token
        });
                            
    } else {
        alert ("Please fill out all the required fields.");
    }
                        
    return false;               
});
```

When I click my #pay_now button (which is a submit button in a form), the Stripe modal comes up.  I enter all the payment information, click Pay and it goes to my thank you/charge page and remains blank

I get an error in firebug that says

Error: Method not allowed: overlayClosed
https://checkout.stripe.com/v2/inner/index.js
Line 13151

Not really sure what the issue is and have tried all I can think of.  Anyone have thoughts?  Thanks!!

Comment: AFAICT: Stripe is doing a JSONP request and the returned payload contains a method name which is not in the whitelist (search that JS file for 'whitelist' and you'll see that it doesn't contain 'overlayClosed'). Are you able to open the 'network' inspection tab in Firebug/Chrome-Web-Inspector and paste in the returned payload from Stripe's request(s) into this SO question? (that may help in figuring out what the problem is -- *ensure you wipe personal info from the payloads if you paste them here*)

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  I figured out what the problem was... there were two things, one I did not have the SSL set up properly... I fixed that pretty quickly, and then spent the day looking at the "network" tab and realized that Multibyte String PHP extension was not enabled causing a 500 error every time I tried to use a Stripe function.  It's working now, so I am pretty happy... thanks for the help